# Notepad++ regex to replace match with the opposite value (true->false, and false->true)?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a large text file with a lot of lines like below, that I'd like to swap the values of. As in, if the value is 1 replace it with 0, if the value is 0 - replace it with 1.

```
Hidden=0
Hidden=1
```

I've worked out the 'find' regex no problem:

```
Hidden\=([01]{1})
```

My problem is working out how to replace it with the opposite.

Comment: If the file is nice enough you coould try with multi-step process - replace zeroes with 00 (or other unique identifier), replace ones with zeroes and 00 to ones.

Comment: @herohuyongtao - This problem is more specific (narrow) and has different possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There's no getting around it - it takes 3 steps:

```
Search   | Replace
Hidden=0 | Hidden=X
Hidden=1 | Hidden=0
Hidden=X | Hidden=1
```

But they're pretty simple.

In case you actually have `Hidden=X` in your code, chose another character for `X` such that `Hidden=?` isn't found.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can setup a regex to do it in 1 pass if you fixup the file ahead of time. This swaps the numbers each pass.

Make sure file is commented like this (easy enough to run a one time regex to add the #0 or #1)

```
Hidden=1 #0 Don't remove (replace with your comment character of choice)
Hidden=0 #1 Don't remove
```

Regex search

```
Hidden\=([01])\s+#([01])
```

Replace

```
Hidden=\2 #\1
```

No other way to do it in one pass unless notepad++ adds support for a regex engine with code expressions.